# sometimes I see quotes for a string in in output

Tags: python-2.7

I am beginner in python as well in coding/scripting.

Case 1 : I see quotes :

formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
print formatter % ("one", "two", "three", "four")

output >> 'one' 'two' 'three' 'four'

Case 2 : I dont see quotes

x = "There are %d types of people." % 10
print x

output >> There are 10 types of people.

Can someone please suggest why this is happening.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

the r in %r stands for representation - it shows the representation for the object which for strings means it has quotes.

%d means formatting the parameter as an integer.

%s is the equivalent for text / strings:

```
>>> formatter = "%s %s %s %s"
>>> print formatter % ("one", "two", "three", "four")
one two three four
```